# Push code from VSTS repository to on-prem TFS?

Tags: selenium, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy

this is my first post on here so forgive me if I've missed an existing answer to this question.

Basically my company conducts off-site development for various clients in government. Internally, we use cloud VSTS, Octopus deploy and Selenium to ensure a continuous delivery pipeline in our internal Azure environments. We are looking to extend this pipeline into the on-prem environments of our clients to cut down on unnecessary deployment overheads. Unfortunately, due to security policies we are unable to use our VSTS/Octopus instances to push code directly into the client environment, so I'm looking for a way to get code from our VSTS environment into an on-prem instance of TFS hosted on their end.

What I'm after, really, is a system whereby the client logs into our VSTS environment, validates the code, then pushes some kind of button which will pull it to their local TFS, where a replica of our automated build and test process will manage the CI pipeline through their environments and into prod.

Is this at all possible? What are my options here?

Comment: Do you use TFVC or Git version control?

Comment: Do you still need the history of source code in your VSTS?

Comment: Yes, still need all code and history in our vsts, but don't need history in client tfs necessarily, just the code

Comment: And its tfvc not git

Comment: Switching to Git does allow you to do this by the way, saving you a lot on integration software,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a direct way to achieve migrating source code with history from VSTS to a on-premise TFS. You would need 3rd party tool, like [Commercial Edition of OpsHub](http://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-visual-studio-migration-utility/) (note it is not free).

Comment: Thanks! Damn that software is expensive. It'll be a tough sell I think, but it's a start

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a new feature that is comming to Octopus Deploy, see https://octopus.com/blog/roadmap-2017 --> Octopus Release Promotions

I quote:
Many customers work in environment where releases must flow between more than one Octopus server - the two most common scenarios being:
Agencies which use one Octopus for dev/test, but then need an Octopus server at each of their customer's sites to do production deployments

Comment: Thanks E. Staal. This was actually the first solution I suggested; that we push the release directly to an octopus server inside the client network. Unfortunately the client shut this down,  as it would simply push a .wsp file and would not allow them to properly audit the code. It also presented the problem of running selenium tests, which we do via vsts, but our own vsts instance can't communicate with the application inside their network.

Comment: So, you're running your selenium tests during the build? Doesn't your build take a very long time? We use Telerik Test Studio and run our tests from Octopus Deploy after we released to a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest the following. Though it contains small custom script.

1. Add build agent to your vsts which is physically located on customer's premises. This is easy, just register agent with online endpoint.
2. Create build definition in vsts that gets code from vsts. But instead of building commits it to local tfs. You will need a small powershell code here. You can add it as custom powershell step in build definition.
3. Local tfs orchestrates the rest.

Custom code:
Say your agent is on d:/agent
1. Keep local tfs mapped to some directory (say c:/tfs)

2. The script copies new sources over some code from d:/agent/work/ to c:/tfs
3. Commits from c:/tfs to local tfs. 
   Note:You will need /force option (and probably some more) to prevent conflicts.

I believe this not as ugly as it sounds.